# Difference between Name and All Fields radio buttons in Lookup dialogue box

Tags: lookup

What is the difference between Name and All Fields radio buttons in the lookup dialogue box.

While using the lookup search option (Name radio button enabled) i couldn't find my value, and while changing the radio button to All fields enabled i am able to see my corresponding searched value.

How can it be changed by using the default settings and displaying my searched value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each object has a Name, usually called Name, but differs in some cases, such as Case Number, First Name/Last Name, etc. This field is always indexed so you can find the record easily.

The two options, Name or All fields, corresponds to the same SOSL functions:

```
FIND {term} IN NAME FIELDS
FIND {term} IN ALL FIELDS
```

The term "All Fields" is kind of misleading, as it doesn't include formulas, picklists, and certain other types of data that isn't indexed. However, it certainly does include pretty much every field you'd find useful to search by, including most custom fields, like text, phone, email, url, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir. And what about retrieving my searched value without enabling the All fields button. Now its like that i couldn't get my searched value from the default settings  Getting the searched value only after enabling the All fields button, else its not showing  any values.